# How to use your js file in default.aspx page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is my JavaScript.js

```
function checkAllCheckBox() {
    var all_checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    if (all_checkboxes.length === all_checkboxes.filter(":checked").length) {
        $('#' + '<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>').css("display", "block");
        $('#' + '<%=btnNextSection.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
        $('#' + '<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>').css("display", "none");
        $('#' + '<%=btnNextSection.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "");
    }
}
```

But when i call it to my Default.aspx file , it is not working

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">

 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I even created that way but it is still not working..

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src='<%# ResolveClientUrl("JavaScript.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any Help appreciate

Thanks

Comment: Where do you call `checkAllCheckBox`? What does your JS console say?

Comment: i call it in .cs file

Comment: @user2407340 Can you post how you are calling the function from your .cs file?

Comment: chkList.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkAllCheckBox()");

Comment: it is working when i put all javascript code in clientside but it is not working when i put that code inside a js file

Comment: where do you put your JavaScript.js file is that is the root folder (the same folder that default.aspx lives)? or on the Scripts folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your method signature and pass in the `btnSubmitClientId` and `btnNextSectionClientId` so it would look something like this:

```
chkList.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkAllCheckBox('#' + '<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>', '#' + '<%=btnNextSection.ClientID %>')");
```

And then your JavaScript function would look like this:

```
function checkAllCheckBox(btnSubmitClientId, btnNextSectionClientId) {
    var all_checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    if (all_checkboxes.length === all_checkboxes.filter(":checked").length) {
        $(btnSubmitClientId).css("display", "block");
        $(btnNextSectionClientId).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
        $(btnSubmitClientId).css("display", "none");
        $(btnNextSectionClientId).attr("disabled", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<%= %>` notation only when JavaScript code is inside of ASPX page markup inside of `<script> ... </script>` block

Comment: <%=  src="JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"%> ijust did this but it shows error ..

Comment: No, what I mean is - if you want to use lines like `<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>` - entire javascript code has to be placed into ASPX page - not a reference to JS file, but actual code itself.

Comment: so what kind of change sould i do ?

Comment: Can you help[ me with this ?

Comment: You said it yourself "*it is working when i put all javascript code in clientside but it is not working when i put that code inside a js file*" that's the only way to make it work if you want to reference page data directly

Comment: but i wan to place it in my js file and call that js file in default.aspx ,this is what i want,if you know the changes i should do , please share it with me

Comment: Then you have to either modify your `checkAllCheckBox()` function to pass ClientIDs as parameters to it or use hard-coded ClientIDs that you can find in rendered HTML source of the page. The fact is you cannot use the likes of `<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>` *outside* of ASPX page